# NullPointerException in AsyncTask onPostExecute on line 1

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have an application that uses bugsense. I'm getting reports of nullpointerexception crashes from bugsense in the onpostexecute method of an asynctask. The strange thing is that the report says that the nullpointer exception happens on com.XXXXXX.XXXXX.projectname.InitRequest.onPostExecute(:1) . And unfortunatelly I cannot reproduce the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.XXXX.XXXX.InitRequest.onPostExecute(:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

and here is the code for the asynctask

```
class InitRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception>>{

private AuthToken authToken;
private int amount;
private InitCallback pic;
private Mode mode;
public boolean st = false;
public InitRequest(AuthToken authToken, int amount,InitCallback pic, Mode mode){
    this.authToken = authToken;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.pic = pic;
    this.mode = mode;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.st = true;
}

@Override
protected Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception> doInBackground(Void... params){

    try{
        Pair<Exception,String> inputStreamOrException = null;
        if (this.mode.equals(DEVELOP)){
            inputStreamOrException  = Utilities.getCorrectInputStream(
                        Utilities.buildURL(XXXX));
        }else {
            inputStreamOrException  = Utilities.getCorrectInputStream(
                    Utilities.buildURL("zzzzz));
        }
        if (inputStreamOrException.second == null){
            return new Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception>(null,inputStreamOrException.first);
        }
        HashMap<String,Object> returnMap = PaypalInitParser.parse(inputStreamOrException.second);
        return new Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception>(returnMap,null);
    }catch (MalformedURLException murle){
        murle.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SAXException saxe){
        saxe.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onCancelled(Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception> result){

    this.st = false;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Pair<HashMap<String,Object>,Exception> result){

    if (result == null){
        if (Helper.context != null){
            ((Interface)Helper.context).FailWithError(new Error(" AUTHORIZATION FAILED","200"));
        }
        this.st = false;
        return;
    }
    if (result.second == null){
        if (result.first != null && result.first.get("error") == null){
            Credentials pc = (Credentials)result.first.get("result");

            if (pic!= null){
                pic.InitFinished(pc);
            }

        }else {
            if (Helper.context != null){
                ((Interface)Helper.context).FailWithError(new Error("AUTHORIZATION FAILED","200"));
            }
        }
    }else {
        if (result.second != null)
            result.second.printStackTrace();

        if (Helper.context != null){
            ((Interface)Helper.context).FailWithError(new Error("AUTHORIZATION FAILED","200"));
        }
    }
    this.st = false;
}
}
```

Has anyone encounter any same/similar error? My only thought is that the main thread of the activity does not exists anymore. But in my activity lifecycle I'm checking if the asynctask is running or is pending and I'm cancelling it in the onPause method of the calling activity.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by adding breakpoint at the first line of the method to know which line encounters the error?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't reproduce the error. I have put a breakpoint before the return of doInBackground and at the first line of onPostExecute and everything seems fine. App does not crash...

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that application doesn't crash if you put a breakpoint, the problem is with the threading. Your code in `AsyncTask` is running before the other code and creating the exception.

I guess in this line, `Credentials pc = (Credentials)result.first.get("result");` result object is not yet instantiated and the exception is being thrown.

So you make sure that all the objects are properly instantiated before you call the `AsyncTask`. Hope this helps!

Comment: if result object is not instantiated, shouldn't onPostExecute enter in the first if : `if(result == null) { ... return; }` ?